# How to wait inside a beforeEach in Angular 4/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, jasmine

One of my components uses a setTimeout inside `ngOnInit`, e.g:

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
      // do some setup stuff using FormBuilder
  }, 100);
}
```

In the unit tests for this component, I need to spy on one of the methods of one of the controls which are built programmatically using FormBuilder, so I am doing this in a beforeEach:

```
describe('testing something', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(component.form.controls.myControl, 'enable');
    });

    it('does something', () => {
      // test stuff
    });

});
```

Before the timeout was added, the test was working perfectly. How can I make the `beforeEach` wait for the 100 ms timeout in the `ngOnInit` method?

I've tried adding `async` and `fakeAsync` to the outer describe, e.g. like this:

```
 describe('testing something', <any>fakeAsync(() => {
     ...
 }));
```

or

```
describe('testing something', async(() => {
     ...
 }));
```

But in the first case, with `fakeAsync` I see a message in the test runner *Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.*, and in the second case it just doesn't even run the test. I also tried wrapping the `it` methods in `fakeAsync` but that doesn't do anything to delay the `beforeEach`

I've tried wrapping the `spyOn` method inside the `beforeEach` in a `setTimeout` and this doesn't appear to have any effect, i.e. the test fails in the same way.

I've also tried using `fakeAsync` with the `beforeEach`, like this:

```
beforeEach(<any>fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(100);
    spyOn(component.modelForm.controls.myControl, 'enable');

  }));
```

But this doesn't work either. It doesn't result in any errors, but the method I want to spy on doesn't exist yet, even after the tick.

How can I force the `beforeEach` to wait for the timeout in `ngOnInit()`? Is it even possible?

Comment: I know the `setTimeout` in `ngOnInit` is terrible. I am not at liberty to change it unfortunately.

Comment: Just to make certain, when running in the async() test were you making use of whenStable() and when running with fakeAsync() were you making use of tick()?

Comment: I didn't try `whenStable`, but I did try `tick(100)` in the `beforeEach` and that didn't help

Comment: This is what fakeAsync is for and it should work as expected without extra actions. This may have something to do with test setup. A way to replicate this would be useful - a https://stackblitz.com or github repo.

Comment: But does `fakeAsync` work with a `describe` rather than an `it`? I am using `fakeAsync` with the `it` method in other tests in the same file

Comment: That's a good point. Yes, that's the problem, I guess. It has no meaning in `describe`. It should be used with beforeEach instead, in conjunction with `tick`.

Comment: `fakeAsync` also doesn't appear to work with `beforeEach`

Comment: @NeilHibbert `whenStable` doesn't appear to have any effect inside a `beforeEach` either. I've only ever seen it used inside an `it`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using Jasmine's `done` callback inside the `beforeEach`, like this:

```
beforeEach((done) => {
    component.ngOnInit();

    setTimeout(() => {
      spyOn(component.modelForm.controls.myControl, 'enable');

      done();
    }, 100);
  });
```

Seems so intuitive!

Answer (score 2):

The following solution can be adapted for beforeEach if needed

```js
before(() => {
  jasmine.clock().install();
})

after(() => {
  jasmine.clock().uninstall();
})

it('test case', () => {
  spyOn(component.modelForm.controls.myControl, 'enable');
  
  component.ngOnInit();

  var timeout = 2000 // 2 seconds
  jasmine.clock().tick(timeout);

  expect(component.modelForm.controls.myControl.enable).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```